# Automatically add HasCallStack constraints on all my functions

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm looking for a compiler flag or something similar that would automatically add the `HasCallStack` context to all of my functions.

I was suggested to enable profiling to get a similar effect but I don't want to recompile my dependencies, and I'd be perfectly fine with only the functions in my application getting annotated.

If there isn't such a flag, why?

Comment: There is no such flag because the designers of GHC are not in the business of gold-plating their compiler (in my opinion, such a flag would be a huge misfeature). GHC [already supports](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/users-guide/phases.html#pre-processor) adding your own custom pre-processors; I'm guessing you could also implement this as a [pluging](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/extending_ghc.html#compiler-plugins). Lastly, is there any reason you can't use your editor to insert the constraint, and from then on write it on new functions?

Comment: Well, we might as well then use editor macros instead of deriving statements, right? No sense in gold-plating the compiler. What about things like the -XStrict and -XStrictData flags? Why not have those as editor plugins as well?

Comment: A preprocessor would probably break all the tooling I have, not to mention I'd have to parse the actual source code.

Comment: Plugins do not require you to parse the source code. If you think it would be a useful feature, feel free to open a ticket or write a proposal (maybe I'm wrong about it being gold-plating!). Regardless, the answer to the question of 'why doesn't it exist' does nothing to solve the problem.

Comment: @user2407038 Don't get me wrong, "people didn't find it useful enough", "too complex to implement", "nobody's gotten around to it yet", etc. are all valid answers to my question. The reason I asked why is because often there are deeper reasons than it seems at first glance.

Comment: There seems to be some discussion on [Trac](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ExplicitCallStack/ImplicitLocations) about this kind of feature, in particular on [ticket 11049](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11049). I'm afraid I don't know enough about it to speak with any authority, but it might give you another direction besides adding `HasCallStack` to all your functions.